# Odd symbols in terminal when running program

Tags: c++, io, symbols

The whole point of this program is to read a list of instructions from a file . On the first pass through I'm just getting the commands on the far left (the only ones without a `\t`) in front of them. I've managed to do that but the problem I'm running into, while I was testing my code to see if I had copied the char array over correctly, is that I'm getting really odd characters to the left side of my output.

Here is the original file I'm reading from: `# Sample Input`

```
    LA 1,3
    LA 2,1
TOP  NOP
    ADDR 3,1
    ST 3, VAL
    CMPR 3,4
    JNE TOP
    P_INT 1,VAL
    P_REGS
    HALT
VAL INT 0
```

The odd output I'm receiving however is:

```
D
D
D
DTOP
DTOP
DTOP
DTOP
DTOP
DTOP
DTOP
DTOP
DVAL
D
D
```

I'm just not sure how I'm getting such a weird output. Here's my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>



using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// If no extra file is provided then exit the program with error message
if (argc <= 1)
{
    cout << "Correct Usage: " << argv[0] << " <Filename>" << endl;
    exit (1);
}

// Array to hold the registers and initialize them all to zero
int registers [] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

string memory [16000];

string symTbl [1000][1000];

char line[100], label[9];
char* pch;

// Open the file that was input on the command line
ifstream myFile;
myFile.open(argv[1]);


if (!myFile.is_open())
{
    cerr << "Cannot open the file." << endl;
}

int counter = 0;
int i = 0;

while (myFile.good())
{
    myFile.getline(line, 100, '\n');

    if (line[0] == '#')
    {
        continue;
    }


    if ( line[0] != '\t' && line[0]!=' ')
    {
        pch = strtok(line-1," \t\n");
        strcpy(label,pch);
    }

    cout << label<< endl;

        }



return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What was the expected output?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The expected output is everything that's in the original output, except for the D's.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed the `else` case for `if ( line[0] != '\t' && line[0]!=' ')`, where you need to give some value to `label` before printing.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would have anything to do with that. I'm getting the correct output, I'm just receiving strange characters overlaying them.

Comment: @cadavid4j: Can you mention the _strange characters_? Or did I miss them?

Comment: The D's are definitely strange and also the newline character shows up overlaying my output when I take away \n from the delimeters list in strtok().

Answer (score 0):

One major problem is that you do not initialize the `label` array, so it can contain any random data, which you then print out. Another problem is that you print the label *each iteration*, even when you don't get a new label.

There are also a couple of other problems with your code, like not checking if `strtok` returns `NULL`, and you should really use `while (myFile.getline(...))` instead of `while (myFile.good())`.

The best way to find out what the cause of your main problem is, is to run your program in a debugger, and step through it line by line. Then you will see what happens, and can examine variables to see if their content is what it should be. Oh, and stop using character arrays, use `std::string` as much as you can.